# CSS Background Disappearing on other Computers

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a background image which I've set on the body of the page. The background appears on my computer but when I go to another computer the background is not there.

```
 body {
   background-image: url("https://sourceneed.com/img/pineapple-1704338_1920.jpg");
   overflow-x: hidden;
   background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

Comment: I think you have to be more specific, same browser? Both PC's have an internet connection? Same network? There could be so many reasons...

Comment: Same browser. Same network. Both PC's

Comment: And just to make sure, if you go to [this link](https://sourceneed.com/img/pineapple-1704338_1920.jpg) on the PC on which the background doesn't work, you can see the image?

Comment: yes, i can see that link @MathijsFlietstra

Comment: Cleared the web browser cache and tried again? Checked the networking tab to see if the browser is actually trying to download the image? Anything strange going on during the request?

Answer (score 0):

If the other device you've tested on is a mobile browser it might not work. The `background-attachment` style has limited support for mobile browsers:

https://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment

Comment: @TheCodersZone using the same browser?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work here:

```css
body {
   background-image: url("https://sourceneed.com/img/pineapple-1704338_1920.jpg");
   
  
   
   overflow-x: hidden;
   background-attachment: fixed;
 }
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: That's funny because all I see when I run your snippet is an empty screen.

Comment: works for me.  Try seeing if you can get the picture at https://sourceneed.com/img/pineapple-1704338_1920.jpg and then run the snippet again

Comment: FYI when I ran the code snippet the first time, I got an empty screen, then followed the link to the image, ran the code snippet again.. and the image showed up...

Comment: you could try sticking this in codepen and see if it works there.  odd behavior

Answer (score 0):

**Its not Computer issue its due to browser or browser version**

**set background image in a div**

```
`#image-div {
background-image: url(img_flwr.gif), url(paper.gif);
background-position: right bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}`
```

**If you want to add background in complete page use cover properties**

```
`html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}`
```